# How to remove @yield when user is authenticated?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm planning to remove @yield in my `default.blade.php` when the user is authenticated. How can I do this within in my if statement?

```
<ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            @if (Auth::check()) <!-- Auth::check() method to test if the user is authenticated, and redirect the user -->

                                            <!-- Auth::user() get the currently logged in user.-->
                <li><a href = "#">Welcome {{ Auth::user()->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#"><img src = "{{ asset('logos/home.png') }}"></a></li>
                <li><a href = "#"><img src = "{{ asset('logos/account.png') }}"></a></li>
                <li><a href = "{{ route('auth.logout') }}"><img src = "{{ asset('logos/logout.png') }}"></a></li>

            @endif
</ul>

@if (Auth::check())
    <div class = "container">
        <a href = "#"><img src = "{{ asset('logos/preregistration.jpg') }}"></a>
        <a href = "#"><img src = "{{ asset('logos/enrollment.jpg') }}"></a>
        <a href = "#"><img src = "{{ asset('logos/studentgrades.jpg') }}"></a>
        </div>

@endif
```

This is my master page where the content belong. `default.blade.php`

```
<body>
@include ('templates.partials.navigation')
<div class = "container">
    @include ('templates.partials.alerts')
    @yield('content') {{-- @yield is always used to get content from a child page into master page. So this page will be master page. --}}
</div>
</body>
```

This is the child page. `home.blade.php` I'm planning to remove my header when the user is logged in.

```
@extends('templates.default') {{---Extending the folder template also the default.blade.php---}}

@section('content')
<h1>Welcome</h1>
@stop
```

Comment: If You want just remove `@yeld` just wrap it with `if` statement. If not try to describe more precisely. Thanks

Comment: @Pyton No this doesn't work. I just duplicate my `@yield`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@if (!(Auth::check()))  @yield('content')  @endif
```